# How to register a property group in blender 2.8

Tags: python

Is there a way to add a property group to this method of registering, without adding a separate register/unregister function?

```
classes = (
    some_scene_variables
    some_operator,
)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

At the moment I am doing this, which works:

```
classes = (
    some_scene_variables,
    some_operator,
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.myvars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = some_scene_variables)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.myvars
```

But it seems wrong to change how I am registering just because I want to add a property group.

Thanks

Edit:
Something similar to this (just for illustration, I know this would in no way work):

```
classes = (
    some_scene_variables
    some_operator,
    bpy.types.Scene.myvars = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = some_scene_variables),

)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Change from what to what? Inheriting from PropertyGroup should work with your code above: class some_scene_variables(bpy.types.PropertyGroup)...

Comment: @squarespiral The first code block shows what is described in the Blender 2.80 manual. `register` and `unregister` are generated using the `register_classes_factory` method. But since they are auto-generated, how would you add the PointerProperty to the scene now?

Comment: So you want to get rid of the lines starting with "bpy.types.Scene.myvars =" and "del bpy.types.Scene.myvars"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Check the source**

As with a lot of blender, can check the code for `bpy.utils.register_classes_factory`

```
def register_classes_factory(classes):
    """
    Utility function to create register and unregister functions
    which simply registers and unregisters a sequence of classes.
    """
    def register():
        from bpy.utils import register_class
        for cls in classes:
            register_class(cls)

    def unregister():
        from bpy.utils import unregister_class
        for cls in reversed(classes):
            unregister_class(cls)

    return register, unregister
```

As you can see it does no more than register unregister classes.  (Notice the reversing of list in unregister)

I would recommend using your own register methods. Even prior, would recommend own register methods over the now defunct `bpy.utils.register_module()`

To still use the factory, in conjunction with your own methods.

```
foo, bar = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

def register():
    foo()
    # do other stuff
```

etc.  Or write your own factory that also takes type, property pairs.