# register group of properties 2.8

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I'm updating my addon to 2.80 and I'm stuck with the new register class system. I try to follow the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127462/how-do-i-register-scene-properties-with-python-in-2-8) but I'm not good enough as a coder to understand the solution.

The problem comes to register my group properties of my UI panel, here is my code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                   BoolProperty,
                   IntProperty,
                   FloatProperty,
                   EnumProperty,
                   PointerProperty
                   )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                   Operator,
                   PropertyGroup
                   )

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    path : StringProperty(
        name="path",
        description="Path to Directory",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='DIR_PATH')

    conform_threshold : FloatProperty(
        name="conform_threshold",
        description="A float property",
        default=0.1,
        min=-5,
        max=30.0)

    invert : BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A simple bool property",
        default = False) 


class UI_PT_LynchonPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Las super herramientas de Juan"""
    bl_label = "Lynchon Tools"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Lynchon Tools"

    def draw(self, context):                                                    
####################Y UP##################################
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.y_up") 

         # Create two columns, by using a split layout.####################MET COMPILER##################################

        split = layout.split()
        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.operator("texture.metal_compiler")

        scn = context.scene
        mytool = scn.my_tool
        col = split.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, 'invert' ,text = "Invert")        

        # Create two columns, by using a split layout. ####################LOW POLY VENUE##################################
        split = layout.split()

        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.label(text="Import Venue")
        col.operator( "xml.lowpolygeneratorparticles")

        # Second column, aligned
        col = split.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="Conform Venue")
        col.operator( "xml.conform_lp_venue")

        # root for export
        scn = context.scene
        mytool = scn.my_tool
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, "path", text="")

        # Create two columns, by using a split layout.  ####################CONFORM HEIGHT##################################
        split = layout.split()

        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.operator("xml.conformheight")

        # Second column, aligned
        scn = context.scene
        mytool = scn.my_tool
        col = split.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, "conform_threshold")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UI_PT_LynchonPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UI_PT_LynchonPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
```

And the error I'm getting back is this one:

```
    location: <unknown location>:-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\Lynchon_tools280\UI.py", line 63, in draw
    mytool = scn.my_tool
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'my_tool'
```

and if I'm not wrong the problem has to do with a register the classes, isn't it?

EDIT

Here my **init** file which registers all my scrits:

```
    import bpy

from . UI import UI_PT_LynchonPanel, MySettings
from . xml_parse_conformHeight import XML_OT_conformheight
from . xml_parse_particles import XML_OT_conformLpVenue, XML_OT_lowPolyGeneratorParticles
from . y_up import LynchOperator
from . metal_compiler import metal_compiler


classes = (UI_PT_LynchonPanel, MySettings, XML_OT_conformheight, XML_OT_conformLpVenue, XML_OT_lowPolyGeneratorParticles, LynchOperator, metal_compiler)


register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

Comment: Your code didn't run the `register()` at all, that's the problem

Comment: @Hikariztw it will depend on how it was run. The error implies it has been registered as it is failing in the panel code. Notice It is in the addon path, the register method of an addon  module is called when enabled.  Quite likely the OP needs to run `bpy.ops.script.reload()` to update changed addons. (this had the shortcut F8 in 2.7x and before).  Or restart blender.  Adding the main thread if at bottom is standard and good practice since it will register the addon in text editor.  Quite often not so useful in an `__init__.py` where relative imports will fail.

Comment: yes sorry about that, already edited the code

Comment: What IMO you want to do is `from . import UI` and in `__init__.py` register method  call `UI.register()` otherwise your custom property will not be registered. (hence the issue)

Comment: That did work, properties were registered correctly but operators got messed up, I'm getting this error for each operator: `C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\Lynchon_tools280\UI.py:83
rna_uiItemO: operator missing srna 'object.y_up'`

Comment: It is the UI equivalent of  `bpy.ops.object.y_up()` could not be found in py console.  Not Registered.... Put a register method in your y_up module and do same.

Comment: That is what confuses me, all my operators are registered in their own scripts like this: 
`classes = (LynchOperator,)
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)`   I thius case LynchOperator  is the class whith "object.y_up" idname

Comment: .. and that method needs to be called when registered my addon module, same as the way mentioned with UI.  The factory creates the method, it still needs to be called. Related and possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128824/how-to-register-a-property-group-in-blender-2-8  As mentioned ditch the factory and add custom register method to each module IMO makes things much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Did you register it?**

EDIT re `__init__.py`

What IMO you want to do is `from . import UI` and in `__init__.py` register method  call `UI.register()` otherwise your custom property will not be registered. (hence the issue seen) *Also IMO Ditch using the register factory, it's not that helpful*

```
from . import UI

def register():
    UI.register()
```

This will call the register method of the UI module.

Former answer below.

Grabbed your code to format it for question edit, added the `if __name__ == "__main__"` bit to make it register if run in main thread (eg text editor) and ran it and it works fine (apart from not having your custom operators *hence the missing buttons in image below*)

[image]

Edited code.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                   BoolProperty,
                   IntProperty,
                   FloatProperty,
                   EnumProperty,
                   PointerProperty
                   )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                   Operator,
                   PropertyGroup
                   )

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    path : StringProperty(
        name="path",
        description="Path to Directory",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='DIR_PATH')

    conform_threshold : FloatProperty(
        name="conform_threshold",
        description="A float property",
        default=0.1,
        min=-5,
        max=30.0)

    invert : BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A simple bool property",
        default = False) 


class UI_PT_LynchonPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Las super herramientas de Juan"""
    bl_label = "Lynchon Tools"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Lynchon Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scn = context.scene
        mytool = scn.my_tool
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.y_up") 


        split = layout.split()
        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.operator("texture.metal_compiler")

        col = split.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, 'invert' ,text = "Invert")        

        split = layout.split()

        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.label(text="Import Venue")
        col.operator( "xml.lowpolygeneratorparticles")

        # Second column, aligned
        col = split.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="Conform Venue")
        col.operator( "xml.conform_lp_venue")

        # root for export
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, "path", text="")

        # Create two columns, by using a split layout.  
        split = layout.split()

        # First column
        col = split.column()
        col.operator("xml.conformheight")

        # Second column, aligned
        col = split.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, "conform_threshold")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(UI_PT_LynchonPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(UI_PT_LynchonPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Note I do not use the blender development addon for vscode from Jaques Lucke,

Comment: You are right, it does run from the text editor, that means is a problem from my `_init_` file?, please check my edit in the original question.

Comment: lol please see my comment under question.

Comment: I'm using the blender development addon for vscode from Jaques Lucke, it should update the addon just by saving

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you with this issue, but I cant manage to make it right. As you stated adding the `def register():` in my `__init__` does the job but not from the start, I need to move it after and before my classes register factory then reupdate the addon in order to get everything registered correctly.  I know it doesn't make much sense.